# Position of only in a sentence and meaning?

Tags: grammar

OK, so I fall down on this one sometimes, but here goes, what sentence means which?

from my geography paragraph;

Only East Anglia was voted the most coastal part in the North London commuter belt.

East Anglia was only voted the most coastal part in the North London commuter belt.

East Anglia only was voted the most coastal part in the North London commuter belt.

East Anglia was voted only the most coastal part in the North London commuter belt.

East Anglia was voted the only most coastal part in the North London commuter belt.

East Anglia was voted the most coastal part in only the North London commuter belt.

East Anglia was voted the most coastal part in the only North London commuter belt.

East Anglia was voted the most coastal part in the North London commuter belt only.

and from my car paragraph - two separate sentences;

Only Renault sold 1,450 vehicles of MPV and 8,000 of commercial vehicles in total last year.
Renault only sold 1,450 vehicles of MPV and 8,000 of commercial vehicles in total last year.
Renault sold only 1,450 vehicles of MPV and 8,000 of commercial vehicles in total last year.
Renault sold 1,450 vehicles of MPV and 8,000 of commercial vehicles only in total last year.
Renault sold 1,450 vehicles of MPV and 8,000 of commercial vehicles in total only last year.
Renault sold 1,450 vehicles of MPV and 8,000 of commercial vehicles in total last year only.

Another paragraph.

Only in Europe, Toyota offers the Camry as the 2.5 GL or 3.5 V6 GLX sedan.

In Europe only, Toyota offers the Camry as the 2.5 GL or 3.5 V6 GLX sedan.

In Europe, Toyota only offers the Camry as the 2.5 GL or 3.5 V6 GLX sedan.

In Europe, Toyota offers the Camry only as the 2.5 GL or 3.5 V6 GLX sedan.

In Europe, Toyota offers only the Camry as the 2.5 GL or 3.5 V6 GLX sedan.

In Europe, Toyota offers the Camry as only the 2.5 GL or 3.5 V6 GLX sedan.

In Europe, Toyota offers the Camry as the 2.5 GL or 3.5 V6 GLX sedan.

And finally, my fourth sentence, which is:

Only John worked with Jane on a Monday when he went off-site.

John only worked with Jane on a Monday when he went off-site.

John worked only with Jane on a Monday when he went off-site.

John worked with only Jane on a Monday when he went off-site.

John worked with Jane on only a Monday when he went off-site.

John worked with Jane on a Monday when only he went off-site.

John worked with Jane on a Monday when he went off-site only.

John worked with Jane on a Monday when he went only off-site.

I'd appreciate any help in ensuring that my sentences read the way I intended, thanks! ;)

Comment: See also [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/115136/where-to-place-only-relative-to-prepositions/115157#115157) and [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3592/using-the-word-only/) (especially the answers).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does it matter where you put “only”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111817/does-it-matter-where-you-put-only) There's more [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111817/does-it-matter-where-you-put-only/111820#111820).

Comment: tyne88, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adverb-position Also, go through previous posts on this site as well as on [ell.se]

Answer (score 0):

The third sentence in the first group, the last sentence in the second group, the second sentence in the third group, and the first sentence in the last group. You can also use words instead of only in this case like just or alone.